# Change default text filter settings in Libreoffice CSV export

Tags: libreoffice, csv

I would like to change the default settings that appear in Libreoffice under Ubuntu, when I click save as csv. I would like to use UTF-8, semicolon and "quote all text fields" as default.

I don't seem to be able to find GUI settings for this, but maybe there is some configuration file I could modify?

I use Kubuntu 16.10, Libreoffice 5.3.0.3, but this is probably irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: Update as of July 2020: still not possible. For example, LibreOffice 6.3.4.2 running on a Mac does not remember the last settings used, and the .config directory has no 'libreoffice' subdirectory.

Comment: @MarkEbden you should report this as a bug. On linux (and Windows for that matter) libreoffice 6.4.5. remembers the settings (and i do not remember a version after 5.4 where this is not the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a user-level configuration file located in below file (tested in Version: 6.0.7.3; thought [as you mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/951908/283843) as of v5.4 it remembers the last settings used):

```
/home/$USER/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

and below parameters controlling those items you desire to change their default values; so change them to the one you want (or add them if they are not exist start from 3<sup>rd</sup> line) like:

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Calc/Dialogs/DBFExport"><prop oor:name="CharSet" oor:op="fuse"><value>76</value></prop></item>
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Calc/Dialogs/CSVExport"><prop oor:name="FieldSeparator" oor:op="fuse"><value>,</value></prop></item>
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Calc/Dialogs/CSVExport"><prop oor:name="QuoteAllTextCells" oor:op="fuse"><value>true</value></prop></item>
```

- the `CharSet` value 76 indicate UTF-8 encoding;
- the `FieldSeparator` is set to comma `,`;
- and `QuoteAllTextCells` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

This still is not possible. However, as of Libreoffice 5.4, Libreoffice remembers the last settings used, which mitigates the negative impact of this missing setting.